# Is the expression “we have to… follow the quick step” idiomatic?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

> In recent years, our country **has a fast development**, and we have to try hard to follow **the quick step**."

I find the first phrase in bold type awkward, is it? Normally, I think it would be *‘our country has seen fast development’* or *‘there has been fast development in our country’*

Does the second expression in bold type have a clear reference? I guess, "the quick step" refers to "fast development" is it a legitimate reference?

Comment: It's an awful sentence.  The verb tense doesn't agree, "a" fast development is wrong, using quick step is adding jargon.  Who knows what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: The sentence was written by a non-native speaker. He probably meant "*Our country has developed rapidly and we [as individuals] have to work hard to keep pace*". You could substitute "*has seen rapid development*" for "*has developed rapidly*", but I find that klunky and pleonastic.

Comment: That's very much what he meant @ Dan Bron. But I guess it depends on readers@ James doesn't seem to understand it?

Comment: @k.k. In order for people to be notified of your comments, you have to make sure there's no space between the `@` and the username.

Comment: I agree with James -- it's a awful sentence.  And "the quick step" is not idiomatic at all.

Answer (score 0):

"Quick step" is likely an error for "quickstep," a lively dance genre in ballroom dancing.  It's faster than the foxtrot or waltz and incorporates fancier footwork called "syncopation."  Go [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUMgTYvf6xU) for a video example.

Metaphorically, it means that in fast economic times, you have to be quick to respond to conditions and nimble in that response.